# Incremental while loop becomes infinite

Tags: javascript, while-loop, directory, infinite-loop

I'm trying to create a new folder with an ascending number on the end if a folder already exists, but I end up in an infinite loop

```
var i=1;
while (myFolder.exists == true) {
var myFolder = new Folder(wf+"/"+curFile+"_folder"+i)
i++;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're constantly redeclaring myFolder and creating new Folders (whatever those are).

Comment: where is the if condition for ending the loop?

Comment: Where is the `myFolder` variable declared before the first iteration of the while loop. The body of the while loop will never get executed because `myFolder` is null, and an error will be thrown.

Comment: Redefining `myFolder` should not be a problem (Javascript hoists that variable in the outer scope). Is this your actual code? Is `exists` a property or a method?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The redefining should be fine, but the first time `while (myFolder.exists == true)` is reached, `myFolder` will be null and this will fail. I think we need more of the surrounding code.

Comment: Please also mention what is the break condition? What are you trying to achieve? We can't guess it!

Comment: @jdwire, you're absolutely right, but then it would not result in an infinite loop. `myFolder` may have been initialized in some part of the code that we do not see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like `myFolder.exists` is a method, not a property, so you have to call it:

```
while (myFolder.exists()) {
    var myFolder = new Folder(wf + "/" + curFile + "_folder" + i);
    i++;
};
```

Otherwise, you would be evaluating the method itself, which is indeed always `true` in a boolean context.

Note in passing that redefining `myFolder` inside the loop is probably not the problem here. Loops in Javascript share the same scope as the enclosing code, and the variable will be hoisted to the start of that scope. As jdwire says, it can be `undefined` initially, but then you would receive an error instead of triggering an infinite loop.